# Javascript validate empty fields

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me on how to validate the javascript form if the
following fields are empty? It doesn't seem to work for my code.

```
function addvalidation(){
        var w = document.forms["shop"]["w"].value;
        var t = document.forms["shop"]["t"].value;
        var a = document.forms["shop"]["a"].value;
        var c = document.forms["shop"]["c"].value;
        var s = document.forms["shop"]["s"].value;
        var c = document.forms["shop"]["c"].value;

        if (w == "" || t =="" || a == ""|| c == "" || s == "" || c == "") {
                alert("Mandatory fields must be filled out");
                return false;
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tn2fvh4p/91/

http://jsfiddle.net/tn2fvh4p/68/

Comment: Works fine in the first jsFiddle.

Comment: You might also check them against null e.g. `w==null | w== "" ...` or use the `required` attribute on your input element.

Comment: whats the problem , this code work fine

Comment: simply use required attribute in your elements. For more fancy validation use jquery validation plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code

```
function addvalidation(){
     var w = document.getElementById("w").value;
     var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
     var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
     var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
     var s = document.getElementById("s").value;
     var c = document.getElementById("c").value;

     if (w == "" || t =="" || a == ""|| c == "" || s == "" || c == "") {
             alert("Mandatory fields must be filled out");
             return false;
         }
```